# not declared in this scope (arrays in C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, file, text, error-handling

I'm a beginner in C++ programming
I have a text file which has 1 million prime numbers separated by spaces. I want to put them in an int array primes[]. Following is the code that I have written:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("C:/Users/DELL/Desktop/primes1.txt");

    //check for error
    if(infile.fail()){cerr<<"Error Opening File"<<endl;
    exit(1);}
    int i=0;
    primes = new int[1000001];
    while(i != infile.eof()){
        infile>>primes[i];
        i++;
    }

    cout<<  primes[4]  <<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I build and run, it gives the following error:

"Error: 'primes' was not declared in this scope"

What is the solution to this?

Comment: Where is your declaration for primes?

Comment: You meant to wrinte `int* primes = new int[1000001];`

Comment: `primes = new int[1000001];` --> `int *primes = new int[1000001];`

Comment: Or allocate on the stack rather than the heap?

Comment: `while(i != infile.eof())` looks very wrong.

Comment: To echo what @FredOverflow said, your loop is very wrong, and it's still wrong after applying advice from the answers below.

Comment: If you've already been question-banned in the past, then you should take more care _this time_, not promising you'll get around to it in the future and begging people not to downvote you in the meantime.

Answer (score 5):

I highly recommend to use a vector instead of an array on the heap to prevent resource leaks:

```
std::vector<int> primes;
int p;
while (infile >> p)
{
    primes.push_back(p);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

C++ <strike>is beautiful</strike> has nice stuff in its library that allows you to do this in a high-level, concise, declarative manner:

```
std::vector<int> primes(std::istream_iterator<int>{infile},
                        std::istream_iterator<int>{});
```

Comment: +1 I'd love to see the C++98 solution as well!

Comment: @FredOverflow substitute the braces for parentheses, and parenthesise either argument to the constructor of `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: Or use std::copy with back_inserter.

Comment: By the way you can replace the second parameter with just {} so
`std::vector<int> primes(std::istream_iterator<int>{infile},{});`
works.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the solution to this?

Declare `primes`. The identifier must be declared first in order to assign something to it.

For example:

```
int *primes = new int[1000001];
```